How do I fix this black square at the bottom of my screen?
I've had this problem for a little while. At the bottom of my monitor, there is this black square that doesn't display anything, almost like there is nothing there.
A few things:
This is a 165hz monitor. When I got it I set the refresh rate to 165hz, and left it. A few months later, this black rectangle thing started.
You can see where the bezel starts, and then there is this black section that isn't displaying anything. When I got the monitor, this definitely wasn't there. (it only started a few months after getting the monitor)
I didn't really mind at the time because it's barely even noticeable, but a few months after that, it looked like this:

Again, you can see where the bezel starts. This black section grew very large.
What I did to fix this temporarily is set the refresh rate to 144hz instead of 165, and that fixed it completely. But then a few months later, lo and behold, this black section started to return like the first picture again, still at 144hz.
I am now at 120hz, and it seems to be starting again. I am not sure what is causing this, but I've narrowed it down a bit:

It has nothing to do with my PC. I know this because if you turn the monitor on without a pc, it will still display the brand name (ASUS in my case), and some other info. When I did this, this black rectangle effect was still there. (therefore I know my drivers aren't causing this, and similarly neither is my GPU) Not to mention that my 2nd monitor has never done this.
It seems to spread like an infection. It starts out like the first picture, and slowly progresses to the state of the second picture. Then if I change the refresh rate, it will go away and then repeat the process a few months later.
I've tried everything I know of, and I'm kind of at a loss.
Any help appreciated!

Hate to bring it to you, but your monitor is faulty. This cannot be magically fixed, it will get worse and worse. You need to replace your monitor. If its still in warrantee, maybe because the amount of dead pixels, they may accept this as a faulty monitor and get you a replacement.

@LPChip Yep, that's honestly what I thought. I will try contacting Asus to see what they say, but I've heard their customer support isn't the best. Thanks for your help!

btw, I have a monitor that has a similar issue. When I turn it on, the entire screen is garbled. But as the monitor warms up, it becomes less and less until at some point the entire picture starts spinning, eventually after a few minutes, the image snaps into place and the monitor works fine after that. But when I let it cool down, the problem repeats. I used to use the monitor for my server so it did not bother me much, and its not what you have, but it shows how weird these panels are created.

@LPChip Yep, after this one’s been on for a while it will reduce in intensity. Sucks that I don’t have the documentation for the warranty, as it is still in the 3 year warranty period.

Do you still have the invoice? you can then contact the shop where you bought it and see if they can do anything for you.

Sounds like a wear and tear issues. I'd ask in a electronics repair shop. It's probably just some "capacitor" that's not delivering enough juice.

I looks like the scaler inside of your display is going bad. This isn't generally a user-serviceable part and you'll want to contact the display manufacturer to see if the unit and this defect is covered by their warranty.
Reducing the resolution and refresh rate that you drive your display at also reduces the workload on the scaler, which allowed the display to continue to work normally despite the failing component.
